# Equivalent definition of continuity in metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am confused at the equivalency of the two statements about continuity in metric spaces.

$f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $x' \in B_\delta(x) \implies f(x')\in B_\epsilon(f(x))$, I know this is equivalent to $d(x,x')<\delta \implies d(f(x),f(x'))<\epsilon$ however I am confused as to why the statement is equivalent to $f(B_\delta(x)) \subset B_\epsilon(f(x))$.

Can someone explain this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $x'\in B_\delta(x)$ if and only if $d(x,x')<\delta$, and $f(x')\in B_\epsilon(f(x))$ if and only if $d(f(x),f(x'))<\epsilon$. Thus, the statement

$$x'\in B_\delta(x)\implies f(x')\in B_\epsilon(f(x))$$

is exactly equivalent to the statement

$$d(x,x')<\delta\implies d(f(x),f(x'))<\epsilon\,:$$

the lefthand sides are equivalent, and the righthand sides are equivalent.